# How do I get the server timestamp in Cloud Functions for Firebase with Firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

How can we get a server timestamp, without using the realtime database 
 but using instead Firestore ?

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'
import { Firestore } from '@google-cloud/firestore'

const db = new Firestore()

export let testIfMatch = functions.firestore
        .document('users/{userId}/invites/{invitedUid}')
        .onCreate(event => {
            let invite = <any>event.data.data()

            if (invite.accepted == true) {
              return db.collection('matches').add({
                friends: [userId, invitedUid],
                timestamp: doc.readTime // <--- not exactly the actual time
              })
            }
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Use server timestamp with Firestore is little different:

```
// Get the `FieldValue` object
var FieldValue = require("firebase-admin").FieldValue;

// Create a document reference
var docRef = db.collection('objects').doc('some-id');

// Update the timestamp field with the value from the server
var updateTimestamp = docRef.update({
    timestamp: FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
});
```

if it's not working you can edit the `var FieldValue = require("firebase-admin").FieldValue;` with `var FieldValue = require("firebase-admin").firestore.FieldValue;`

Comment: Thanks, `require("firebase-admin").firestore.FieldValue;` works, but `require("firebase-admin").FieldValue;` doesn't

Comment: @GrafOrlov I edited, because the documentation was without `firestore`

Comment: Yes, `require("firebase-admin").firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();` is correct.

Comment: can you please explain more about this package **firebase-admin**, should I import it into the app.module ? After installing this package `ng serve` stopped working for and I get a lot of errors

Comment: You can import it ` import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'
import { Firestore } from '@google-cloud/firestore' `  like this

Comment: @PiniCheyni sorry, wrong read... No, this is for using it in cloud functions not in Angular, use AngularFire 2 for that

Comment: Is this supposed to work in a browser as well, or only in Node?

Answer (score 10):

Here's a slightly more concise way of doing it:

`import * as admin from "firebase-admin"`

`const timestamp = admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();`

Answer (score 1):

Here's my way of doing it. It doesn't require adding `'@google-cloud/firestore'` as a dependency to your project, and eliminates adding lots of `admin.firestore.xxx` to your code.

```
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

import FieldValue = admin.firestore.FieldValue;
// import anything else you want to alias

someRef.set({timestamp: FieldValue.serverTimestamp()});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Firestore, you can use such below code snippet.

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore()

val ts = db.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using "firebase-admin": "10.0.0"
You can use the below snippet.

```
const {FieldValue} = require('firebase-admin/firestore');
const timestamp = FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
```