# Is there any way to use FieldValue.serverTimestamp() in Firebase Firestore JS without Firebase-Admin

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

According to answer below, Firebase-Admin is required to use FieldValue.serverTimestamp().

[How do I get the server timestamp in Cloud Functions for Firebase with Firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46647964/how-do-i-get-the-server-timestamp-in-cloud-functions-for-firebase-with-firestore) .

But I am using only Firebase JS and Firebase Firestore JS. The application runs only in client side.
However, Firebase-Admin requires a server.

Is there any way to use server timestamp when doing a write operation ?

Comment: `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` available in all client SDKs, [including Javascript](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue).

Comment: @BobSnyder Thanks. It worked.

Comment: yeah using this solves it in your object to add: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()

Answer (score -3, accepted):

**This answer is outdated, check above answer!**

Simply use `Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` within your object.

Like this:

```
ref.set({ time: Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP })
```

Comment: What is the difference with `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`?

Comment: @wonsuc this answer is related to the realtime database. Your code works for firestore.

Comment: Sorry, I had to downvote, since OP is talking about Firestore.

Comment: This should in fact be not the accepted answer, since it confuses people. @Leonardo

Answer (score 6):

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.md#servertimestamp

```js
import { serverTimestamp } from "firebase/firestore";

addDoc(collection(db, 'your_collection'), {
  ...
  createdAt: serverTimestamp()
})
```

Answer (score 3):

you can get the instance from your firebase instance:

```
firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
```

Comment: What can I use now because, `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` not working now on web

Answer (score 0):

try to import firebase like this -

```
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
```