# Timestamp for firestore collections

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Trying to find out the new way to show a timestamp in collections, usually it just used to be

timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()

im using the timestamp key aswell if that changes anything, I cannot find it anywhere, apparently they updated it as there was an issue?

```
db.collection('posts').add({
              message: input,
              timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
              profilePic: user.photoURL,
              username: user.displayName,
              image: image,
            })
```

Thanks

Comment: "apparently they updated it as there was an issue?" This is impossible to help with. Please show [what you tried that doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), or link to the source that caused your confusion.

Comment: ive edited as above, this does not work anymore and they have updated it , then in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46913824/is-there-any-way-to-use-fieldvalue-servertimestamp-in-firebase-firestore-js-wi

they explained to use Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP

none of them work , neither does this https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.FieldValue

Comment: "this does not work anymore" Why not? What is the problem when you run this code? Is there an error message? Did you compare it to the documentation? https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#server_timestamp

Comment: yes exactly the error is Cannot read property 'FieldValue' of undefined

Comment: So can you show how you import `firebase`? Essentially: we need to be able to copy/paste your code into a file of our own and reproduce the problem. I highly recommend checking out [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as following the guidance in there drastically increases the chance that we can help.

Comment: you wont believe it, all had to do was change import firebase from "firebase" instead of "./firebase". thanks anyway mate cheers