# export 'firestore' (imported as 'firebase') was not found in 'firebase' after upgrading to firebase js sdk v8

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angularfire

I have upgraded the firebase JS SDK from v7 to v8.0.0 and I am importing firebase like so.

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
```

Accessing any of the following causes the error below.

```
firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
firebase.User
firebase.auth.UserCredential
```

> export 'firestore' (imported as 'firebase') was not found in
> 'firebase'
> Property 'firestore' does not exist on type 'typeof
> import("appPath/node_modules/firebase/index")'

I have found a workaround by changing firebase to firebase.default e.g.

```
firebase.default.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
```

**Is this the correct approach to resolve this?**

EDIT: I am also using AngularFire in the project.
I tried using:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
export const firestore = firebase.firestore();
```

But this gave me the following error:

> Uncaught FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been
> created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I ran into the same problem when I updated to Angular 11. I tried the fix to install the firebase-admin library and followed the directions from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63866512/11064290), but that is not supposed to run in a browser and caused some other issues, so I abandoned that.

I noticed from the [release notes](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/version-6-upgrade.md) of AngularFire that the latest version does not support older versions of the JS SDK, which is where this function comes from, and so I deleted node_modules, the package-lock.json file, and ran npm cache clean --force and then npm install to run clean. That did nothing, but I felt accomplished.

And then I ran into [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64545862/upgrade-to-firebase-js-8-0-0-attempted-import-error-app-is-not-exported-from) which explained my issue and got things to compile by changing the library from

> 'import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

to

> import firebase from 'firebase/app';

That removed the "cannot find firestore" error and it compiled correctly. Works with the original code:

> get firebaseTimestamp() {
> return firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
> }

Hope this helps - it was a sticky bug.

Comment: See: https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#version_800_-_october_26_2020

Comment: in case of React, the explanation: In versions 9.0.0 and later, Firebase has introduced a new modular SDK. This new SDK provides a simpler and more intuitive API, with improved performance and better tree shaking. So, when using Firebase with React, it's recommended to use the new modular SDK  `firebase/compat/app` and import the specific packages that your project needs, instead of the older namespaced SDK.

Answer (score 31):

For those getting similar error on version 9 Firebase, make sure to change your path to:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
...
```

instead of:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/firestore';
...
```

Taken from [firebase doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade)

Comment: It works perfectly! Thanks. Could you please tell me how you know about this change?

Comment: @Sobhani No prob! Tbh found out recently myself when I was re-iterating one of my client projects. Noticed a v8.x.x -> v9.x.x update so checked the docs for any major changes.

Comment: worked for me thank you brother !

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/database";
```

instead of

```
'import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
```

This may help

Answer (score 3):

**Before: version 8**

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/firestore';
```

CHANGE TO ====>

After: version 9 compact

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi here the form that i use

> import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';

---

> import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';

Hope it help's !

Answer (score 0):

Actually you just have to do:

```
import "firebase/compat/database"; // in angular-fire-database.js

import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app'; // in angular-fire.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Compiled with problems: export 'default' (imported as 'firebase') was not found in 'firebase/app'

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { auth } from '../misc/firebase';
```

According to v9 update, I've changed the import statement but the error still persists

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
```

Comment: So, alongwith the files where you're using firebase, you've to update the new syntax in firebase.js too. I kind of missed on that, that's why the error keeps occurring.

Changes made:
`import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth'; `

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your `config.js` file lies in how you are initializing the Firebase storage and `Firestore` instances.

In Firebase version 9 (also known as Modular SDK), the method of initializing Firebase and accessing its services has changed. You should use the modular Firebase SDK syntax instead of the namespace import approach used in Firebase version 8 and below.

Here's how you can correct your `config.js` file using the Firebase Modular SDK syntax:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";
```

Answer (score 0):

Incase of React. For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later.

Suppose, You want to upload media files such as images.

Follow these Steps:

1. Create a directory in **src/firebase/firebaseConfig.js**

```
/** src/firebase/firebaseConfig.js */

// FIREBASE: SDK

// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
// Add Your own Firebase Creditentials
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
  measurementId: "",
};

// Initialize Firebase
const firebaseapp= initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Export
export { firebaseapp };
```

2. In your Upload Script Add this

```
/** imageUpload.js */
// Export the firebase from: src/firebase/firebaseConfig.js
import firebaseapp from "/firebase/firebaseConfig";
import { getStorage, ref } from "firebase/storage";

// init the firebase app
const storage = getStorage(firebaseapp);

// Get a Storage Reference and Then Upload Files: file refer to image file
const storageRef = ref(storage, `images/` + file.name);
const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file);

// Check your firebase, files will be uploaded there
```

Checkout official documentation: [Firebase Storage Web](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/start)