# export 'Timestamp' (imported as 'Timestamp') was not found in > '@angular/fire/firestore

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2, angularfire

I have just upgrade my app from ionic 5 to 6 with

1. angular 13 and
2. angular/fire - 7.2.0
3. firebase 9.6.3

same error coming in

FacebookAuthProvider
OAuthProvider
GoogleAuthProvider

and importing timestamp is causing issues with below error

Other than this all imports from '@angular/fire/firestore working well

> export 'Timestamp' (imported as 'Timestamp') was not found in
> '@angular/fire/firestore' (possible exports: Firestore,
> FirestoreInstances, .......)

tried [export 'firestore' (imported as 'firebase') was not found in 'firebase' after upgrading to firebase js sdk v8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65658510/export-firestore-imported-as-firebase-was-not-found-in-firebase-after-up)  but no luck

Comment: What version of angular fire were you on before?

Comment: "@angular/fire": "7.0.4", –

Comment: I just solved Timestamp error using import from firebase/firestore instead of angular/fire. but this trick not working in case of FacebookAuthProvider, OAuthProvider 
 and GoogleAuthProvider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Subscribing to a firebase stream You could convert any field with Timestamp  type to date type:
Let's suppose We have a document has a field named createdAt:

```
const createdAt = new Date(createdAt.seconds * 1000 + createdAt.nanoseconds/1000000);
```